# Raster calculator and Zonal Statistics as a table do not work on joint combined raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, raster-calculator, zonal-statistics

I combined 3 raster files in ArcMap 10.4 and then joined 3 .dbf table to the combined raster and exported the result to a new .tif file.

Now I am trying to run "Raster calculator" and "Zonal Statistics as a table". However none works on the joint fields. The result that I get from these two shows that they have been only applied on the Value and Count Fields.

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! Can you include more details about what you've done so far? It will help people be able to answer your question. What tool are you using to combine the rasters? How are you joining the tables to the combined raster? What data is supposed to be in the joined tables? What inputs are you giving to Raster Calculator and Zonal Statistics as Table?

Comment: Use lookup on any of additional tool.